# PyODBC works but SQLAlchemy does not. Throws "UnicodeDecodeError" for Tibco ODBC

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, odbc, pyodbc, tibco

I am trying to connect to Tibco Virtualization Server. I have an ODBC DSN on my windows machine using driver `TIBCO(R) Data Virtualization 8.0`.

Connection with PyODBC **works**

```py
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('dsn=' + "Tibco_DSN")

sql_query = 'SELECT top 5 * FROM my_table'

cur = conn.cursor().execute(sql_query)
for row in cur:
    print(row)
```

Connection with SQLAlchemy **doesn't**

```py
import sqlalchemy
conn_str = "mssql+pyodbc://@Tibco_DSN"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)

connection = engine.connect()    # error here

sql_query = 'SELECT top 5 * FROM my_table'
cursor = connection.execute(sql_query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows) 
connection.close()
```

Error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 0: invalid start byte`

I can confirm that SQLAlchemy is able to authenticate to server (hence connect). But not able to query.

I have tried adding `?charset=utf8` to `conn_str` but no good.

I have to use SQLAlchemy as most of the app needs ORM.

Comment: Is Tibco Virtualization Server 100% compatible with MS SQL Server (T-SQL and the TDS protocol)? If not, then `mssql+pyodbc` won't work; you'd need a SQLAlchemy dialect specifically written for Tibco.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks, however I am not sure, can't find on documentation too.

Comment: Just to add, `pyodbc` connection works with Pandas as well and shows the data. Its only SQLAlchemy ORM that does not work.